# Воспроизведение аудио по ссылке

Tags: javascript, html, вёрстка, аудио

Имеем:

- поток URL радиостанции;
- сайт, на котором есть пункт меню "Радио".

Требуется:

- при нажатии на пункт меню, начинается воспроизведение потока;
- при повторном нажатии - его остановка.

Желательно при воспроизведении пункт меню меняет цвет (`.active{` реагирует на сделанное нами).
Есть вещь ниже, но нажатие однократное, отключить невозможно:

```
<audio id="audio" src="https://www.nostalgie.be/radioplayer/" autoplay="false" ></audio>
<a onclick="playSound();"> Play</a>
<script>
function playSound() {
      var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
      sound.play();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Отключить трансляцию можно командой **sound.pause();**

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <title>Document</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <audio id="audio" src="" autoplay="false" ></audio>
        <a id="psound" onclick="playSound();">Play</a>
        <script>
        function playSound() {
            var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
            sound.play();
            document.getElementById("psound").setAttribute("onclick","PauseSound()");
        }
        function PauseSound(){
            var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
            sound.play(); 
            document.getElementById("psound").setAttribute("onclick","playSound()");
        }
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```